# Netsuite POST call gives error, Unsuported number format

Tags: javascript, netsuite, postman

I am trying to do simple POST request to my script in netsuite,
but i always get this error.

```
{
   "error":{
      "code":"SYNTAX_ERROR",
      "message":"SyntaxError: Unsuported number format: ------- (null$lib#3)"
     }
}
```

My script looks like this

```
function putRESTlet(dataIn) {
  if ("command" in dataIn) {
    return {"result": "command found"}
  } else {
    return {"result": "wrong command"}
  }
}

function getRESTlet() {
  return {"result":"Get result"}
}
```

GET call works fine, PUT & POST gives me that Error

I cant see any reason why it gives me this error, cause i dont use any numbers.

Comment: What are you sending in the request body? Did you set the Content Type to json?

Comment: Yes, Content Type is application/json, and payload is simple 
`{ command: getInvoice }`

Answer (score 0):

Okay found it out myself, i was trying to send form-data with Postman to Netsuite, and then netsuite did not like that format, now i send raw format and it works.